# Running Script to test new ram in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04

I just added one GB of RAM to an Acer Aspire 1600, how do I check with script to see if running a little bit faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time` to time a process for example.

```
time du -h
```

replacing du -h with a process that you know uses a lot of RAM.

Collect the data with and without the RAM installed and compare.